# How do I show database results, based on what the user clicks? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but it looks like I am still not sure how Rails is supposed to work when it comes to making extra pages.

I have a devise user model (and a user controller) which has an integer field "account_type" for each user - 0 for Admin, 1 for Manager and 2 for Caller.

I know how to use the index page to show all types of users. However, how do I make a page that shows results based on what I click on? For example, I have 3 buttons in the menu:

1. Admins
2. Managers
3. Callers

When I click on Admins, I should see only the admins. When I click on Managers, I should see only managers etc.

That's all I have for the controller and now sure how to change it, but also not sure how to even link the new pages in the views.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def index 
    @users = Users.all
end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple and RESTful way would be to just create different routes for each type:

```
resources :admins, only: [:index]
resources :managers, only: [:index]
resources :callers, only: [:index]
```

This creates the routes `/admins`, `/managers`, `/callers` that each go to a separate controller:

```
class AdminsController
  # GET /admins
  def index
    @users = User.admin 
    render 'users/index'
  end
end

class ManagersController
  # GET /managers
  def index
    @users = User.manager
    render 'users/index'
  end
end

class CallersController
  # GET /callers
  def index
    @users = User.caller
    render 'users/index'
  end
end
```

To create a button that goes to each type of user the simplest and most accessible way is to just use good old links and style them to look like a button.

```
<%= link_to 'Admins', admins_path %>
<%= link_to 'Managers', managers_path %>
<%= link_to 'Callers', callers_path %>
```

You also want to setup [ActiveRecord::Enum](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to handle your integer column:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  enum account_type: {
    admins: 0,
    managers: 1,
    callers: 2
  }
end
```

The next step would be to refactor and cut duplication if needed.

Comment: Wow, thank you SO much! This was so helpful, I haven't come across any of that in all my lessons, so I definitely have a better understanding. I already had the enums set up, I was missing the knowledge on creating the separate routes.
I do have a follow-up question: am I supposed to generate 3 new controllers (admin, manager, caller)? Or am I supposed to put those classes within the UserController class... But when I do the latter, I get "uninitialized constant AdminsController", so I guess it's the first?

Comment: I now created separate controllers and it works! I would still love to learn if making new controllers was the only (and recommended) solution.

Comment: It's not the only way - but it is a clean, simple and extendable way. You could also use a query string parameter `/users? account_type=admin` and handle it all through your `UsersController#index` method but that will result in a lot of code shoehorned into a single method. You can add query string parameters to links or use forms to send GET requests. This isn't really the kind of thing you'll find in tutorials as it's really just a matter of applying fundamentals (REST, MVC) to solve the very common case where the relationship between controller and model is not 1:1.